# How to target and remove a given fieldset within drupal

Tags: drupal, fieldset, hook-form-alter

I am very new to drupal and have been playing around with lots of different modules and core features. I have now come to an issue I have been trying to solve for the pass 48hrs without finding the right solution.

I am building a forum, using the core module, but my problem is when users post a new topic / comment, they are given the option of selecting which 'text format' they want to use. I want drupal to take it as given that filtered HTML is the only option and not offer the use a 'plain text' format.

I can just target the fieldset's id with 'display:none' in CSS and that does work, will not display any more, but I would like to know how to remove the fieldset code itself.

I have tried this,

```
function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
unset($form_id('edit-body-und-0-format');
 }
```

The 'edit' id is the id on the fieldset for the text options, but all this does is give me the white screen of death....

So what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help given....

Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this with code, you can do it via the admin interface, in Drupal 7 do this:

Go to: `Configuration->Content Authoring->Text formats` Turn off the formats for the roles.

If you are using a **wysiwyg editor** you can also change it per profile go to:  `Configuration->Content Authoring->wysiwyg profiles`

Comment: It will not let me do this! I want 'Filtered HTML' as the only option and for the text format feildset not to appear but you can not, or my drupal install will not let me disable / remove the Plain Text format, so it always gives users the option of selecting Plain or filtered!